# Is $L^*L$, where $L^*$ denotes the formal adjoint, positive semi-definite?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators

Let $E$, $F$ be vector bundles with metric over a smooth (not necessarily compact) manifold $X$.
Let $L:C^\infty(E) \rightarrow C^\infty(F)$ be a differential operator.
Let $L^*:C^\infty(F) \rightarrow C^\infty(F)$ be the formal adjoint of $L$ with respect to the $L^2$-inner product on the $L^2$-sections of $E$ and $F$, i.e. $L^*$ satisfies:
$$
\langle L f,g \rangle_{L^2(F)} =
\langle f, L^*g \rangle_{L^2(E)}
$$
for all $f \in C^\infty(E)$, $f \in C^\infty(F)$ with compact support.

Then $L^*$ is again a differential operator and can therefore be applied to all smooth sections of $F$.

> Question:
> Are all eigenvalues of $L^*L$ acting on smooth sections non-negative?
> Here, smooth sections need not be in $L^2$.

$L^* L$ acting on $L^2_2(E)$ has only non-negative eigenvalues, because of
$$
\langle L^* L f, f \rangle 
=
\langle Lf, Lf \rangle
=
|L f|^2 \geq 0.
$$
But according to what I know, it could be possible that there exists some section $f \in C^\infty(E)$ that is not in $L^2_2(E)$, for example because its $L^2$-integral is infinite, but satisfies $Lf=-f$.

Context about my application:
I am interested in the case where $P$ is a principal bundle over an asymptotically conical manifold, $A$ is an asymptotically flat connection on $P$, and $L=\nabla_A$ on $\operatorname{Ad} P$.
I am also interested only in sections $f \in C^\infty(E)$ which decay at infinity, but they may not decay fast enough to be in $L^2(E)$.

Comment: Would not the be enough to have that $\langle Lf,Lf\rangle=|Lf|^2\ge0$ ?

Comment: @KBS I wrote down this line in my question. I understand this holds for $L^2$-sections. For sections which are not in $L^2$, the expression $\langle Lf, Lf \rangle$ may not be finite. I don't see how the knowledge of $L^2$-sections tells me something about smooth sections which are not in $L^2$.

Comment: No, it does not seem you wrote that but this may be a typo. Please check. Otherwise, I would say that in your case, you may need to consider that $Lf$ is in $L^2$ otherwise $\langle Lf,Lf\rangle$ does not make much sense as well as taking the adjoint. Would that be a technical issue to consider that?

Comment: Also, perhaps should also add details on the spectral properties of the operator $L$ for people who are more specialized to operator theory and may not know this type of operators (I am probably one of those).

Comment: Assuming $L^*f$ is well-defined for an arbitrary smooth section $f$, does it not work to reduce to the $L^2$ case by multiplying $f$ with a sequence of bump functions that exhaust $X$ and take a limit?

Comment: @KBS Thanks! (1) There was a typo, I meant to write $\langle Lf,Lf \rangle = |Lf|^2 \geq 0$. I fixed this. (2) You are right in that $Lf$ must be in $L^2$, not $f$. I added this requirement by saying in my definition of formal adjoint, that I only consider smooth sections with compact support. (3) Spectral properties of $L$: I don't know any. In fact, I realised that I am interested in the more general question where $L$ is an operator between different vector bundles. I added this to the question. That makes it even harder to formulate spectral properties of $L$, though.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I tried this method but couldn't turn it into a proof. It is correct that $L^* f$ is well-defined for an arbitrary smooth section $f$. I want to prove: if $L^*Lf=\lambda \cdot f$ for a number $\lambda$, then $\lambda \geq 0$. Let $f_k$ be a sequence of smooth cut-offs of $f$ converging to $f$. If I could take $f_k$ to be eigenfunctions of $L^* L$, then taking the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$ in $L^* L f_k=\lambda_k f_k$ would prove my claim. But I cannot assume $f_k$ are eigenfunctions of $L^* L$. Were you thinking something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is: No.

Example: take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $E$ and $F$ to be the trivial bundle over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $L=\frac{d}{dt}$.
Then $L^*=-\frac{d}{dt}$ and $L^*L=-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$, i.e. the operator $L^*L$ is the Laplacian in one dimension.

Let $f(t)=e^{t}$, then $L^*L (f)=-f$, i.e. $f$ is an eigenfunction of $L^*L$ for the negative eigenvalue $-1$.

(The answer to the refined question from "Context about my application"  in the original post may still be positive, I don't know that.)